# Best way of Splitting up and then putting back a huge dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, sentiment-analysis, corpus

Basically I have a dataframe with 300 000 rows, which I need to do sentiment analysis on. The dataframe contains reddit comments, so I need to transform them into corpus, but the function I have only works on 10 000 rows :

```
IntelCorpus1 %>% tm_map(content_transformer(tolower)) %>% tm_map(removePunctuation) %>% 
  tm_map(removeNumbers) %>% 
  tm_map(removeWords, stopwords("english")) %>% 
  tm_map(stemDocument) %>% 
  tm_map(stripWhitespace) -> IntelCorpus1
```

Basically I will need to split the 300 000 dataframe up into 10 000 parts, use this corpus function on them and then sentiment analyse it with:

`IntelSentiment1 <- analyzeSentiment(IntelCorpus1)`

After which I need to put it back together. It's important that it keeps the order, because there is a date variable which I will need.

What would be the best way to go about this, without repeating the same code 30 times?
Not sure if split() would work?

Comment: you need to split `IntelCorpus1` into 10,000 parts, because `analyzeSentiment` can only take 10,000 rows of `IntelCorpus1`, right?  Does the function return a dataframe, i.e. Is `IntelSentiment` a new dataframe?

Comment: It's more of a RAM limitations, since the vector created will use like 20-30 gb of RAM, but yeah, about 10,000 is what it can take. And yes, IntelSentiment is a new dataframe, intelcorpus is a large Simple corpus. @langtang

Comment: Or does `IntelCorpus1` represent the "first" of 30 splits of some larger `IntelCorpus`?  I can make my answer below more relevant, if I know which of these (the pipeline in the code block or the `analyzeSentiment()` function is the one that is limited to 10,000 rows

Comment: IntelCorpus1 is the first 10,000 rows of the main dataframe. The limiting factor is that the analyzeSentiment() will use too much RAM, so the code won't run, so that is why I have to break it down. It's not exactly 10,000, but it's around that much my pc can run. @langtang

Comment: Well, I deleted my answer, as perhaps you didn't find it helpful. You can still use the same approach (make an indicator for the 30 or so groups, and loop through the subsets, each time running the `tm_map()` calls, and feeding the result of that pipeline to the `analyzeSentiment()` function.  You may run into trouble if the RAM is not quickly released after each run through the function, i.e. before the next interation of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Consider a defined method to run your process and split data into `by` (the object-oriented wrapper to `tapply` to split data frames and pass subsets into function).

```r
run_process <- function(sub) {
    subIntelCorpus <- sub %>% 
        tm_map(content_transformer(tolower)) %>%
        tm_map(removePunctuation) %>% 
        tm_map(removeNumbers) %>% 
        tm_map(removeWords, stopwords("english")) %>% 
        tm_map(stemDocument) %>% 
        tm_map(stripWhitespace)

    subIntelSentiment <- analyzeSentiment(subIntelCorpus)

    return(subIntelSentiment)
}

splits <- ceiling(1:nrow(MainIntelCorpus)/10000)

sentiment_frames <- by(MainIntelCorpus, splits, run_process)

FinalIntelSentiment <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, sentiment_frames)
```